# No Internet connection inside Docker container (not NAT / DNS issue)

Tags: networking, dns, iptables, docker, nat

Good morning,

As said in the title, I have problem with Docker : there is no internet connection for my Laravel App inside Docker.

It is not a DNS or NAT masquerading issue, I've already checked iptables -t nat and I use IP address (not domain name) to access to external SMTP server.

However, it still have issue: "Connection could not be established with host 89.xxx.xxx.xxx".

I'm new with Docker so I think I made the beginner's mistake, but I didn't found it.

On docker-compose.yml:

```
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Result with iptables -t nat -nL (only relevant rows):

```
manoaratefy@manoaratefy-hb ~ $ sudo iptables -t nat -nL

(...)

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.18.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0

(...)       

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 to:172.18.0.2:443
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 to:172.18.0.2:80
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306 to:172.18.0.3:3306
```

Do you have any suggestions for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your iptables dump shows two 'RETURN' rules at the very top of the DOCKER chain, which imply that the rest of the chain is never reached. Can you verify what happens if these rules are removed? (It also does not show how the DOCKER chain is invoked at all; I don't see any "-j DOCKER" rules in the PREROUTING chain.)

Comment: My full iptables -t nat -nL result: https://pastebin.com/iV2jVN0H

Comment: These rules has been automatically created by Docker. Is there something I should do with Docker to modify these rules or should I change it directly into IPTables?

Comment: Hmm, would be great if you could post it in the format of `iptables -t nat -S` or at least `iptables -t nat -vnL`, as the default "summary" format often omits important details (like whether the rules are interface-specific).

Comment: Here is it: https://pastebin.com/MyeCNh0t / https://pastebin.com/9rq9yFtr